# My Array does not use the variables specified earlier?

Tags: java

I have two private objects with custom classes initialized without assigning values to them.

```
private Object var0, var1 var2, var3, var4;
```

Later, in the same class, I put all of them into an array and try to assign values to them using a for loop like this:

```
Object[] variables = {var0, var1, var2, var3, var4};
```

```
for (xy) {
variables[i] = new Object(cords[0], cords[1], randomFunc1(), randomFunc2(), ObjectVar.TYPE);
}
```

But the IntelliJ Debugger shows me that the actual variables created at the head of the class aren't touched and are still "null". Due to that, I can't access the recently created variables anymore.
When I manually assign values like this,

```
var0 = new Object(x, y, value0, value1, value3);
```

there is no problem and everything works. Unfortunately it is not as easy as it is here and each line would take way more code than my first, not working, solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: You definitely will need to show us much more of your code before we can even try to give you a useful answer.  We'll need to see the `Object` class, the `for(xy)` details, where `variables` is defined...

Answer (score 0):

`var0` is still a pre-declared variable. `variables[0]` is **its own reference**, not the same as `var0`.

If you need "numbered variables", only use a array or list, not individual objects.

```
Object[] variables = new Object[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  variables[i] = cords[i];
}
variables[2] = randomFunction1();
...
```

Comment: So what would you recommend to change/where can I read and learn more about it? Didn't find anything on google :/

Comment: Read about what? Referential equality?

Comment: just forget about it, I thing I don't have the technical understanding of java to understand that for now. But thank you for your answer, your code snipped helped me to solve my problem :)

Comment: This problem is not unique to Java. Each variable is a reference to space in memory. An array allocates continuous, unique space, to which it can _reference other references_, not "copy them".

Comment: all object oriented languages or just java and some other? just out of curiosity

Comment: Javascript, for example, is not "object oriented", and would have the same issue when using an array of pre-declared variable references.